# How do I prove that a fast spinning disk requires more force to stop it than a slowly spinning disk?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia

I am trying to prove that with all things the same, a rapidly spinning disk requires more force to stop it than a slowly spinning one.

For example, when you first hit the brakes in a fast moving car, you must hit them really hard to get lock up.  But if the car is moving more slowly,  it doesn't take nearly as much force to do it.  I just can't find equations to prove it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It doesn't.  You can stop any spinning disk with any amount of force.  You just have to apply it for longer if you have a higher angular velocity.

Comment: I would remove the moving car from the question, since the car itself is in linear motion.  The answers have all ignored the "car" part in order to give good answers.  Instead, perhaps ask about something like a free spinning front wheel on an upside-down bicycle, or perhaps a spinning wheel on a car that is on jacks and not moving.

Comment: To @WayneConrad's point, I'm not sure about your assertion about cars.  My experience is that it's really hard to lock up the brakes on a slowly moving car.  There are so many factors involved, though.  Is that ultimately your question?  I'm getting an 'argument with a friend' vibe.

Comment: @JimmyJames I think I see what you're saying.  My objection doesn't make as much sense as I thought it did.

Answer (score 6):

**No, not necessarily.** Equating rotational energy of disk and work done stopping a disk fully when it makes $\Delta \theta$ accumulated angle until it stops, gives :
$$ \frac 12 I\omega^2 = \tau \Delta \theta_{stopping} \tag 1$$

So you either need high torque over short stopping angle $\Delta \theta_{stopping}$, or low torque over long stopping angle.
By analogy with cars,- you can stop a car in a long breaking distance if you push a break very weakly or,- stop car in short distance when breaks are pushed more strongly (of course until ABS kicks-in).

So all in all - situation depends on your requirements on *how fast* you want to deplete given rotational energy of disk.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the concept of angular momentum.

Angular momentum ($L$) is given as:-

$L~=~Iω$

$I$ is the moment of inertia.

$ω$ is the angular velocity.

Assume that all the particles of both the discs are identical and have same mass and both the discs have same moment of inertia.

This means that the fast spinning disc will have more angular momentum as compared to the slow spinning disc.

In order to stop the discs from spinning, we need to give the disc the same magnitude of angular momentum but in the opposite direction.

The rate of change of angular momentum is moment of force.

This implies that the fast spinning disc will need more opposing moment of force to come to rest than the slow spinning disc if the time interval to come to rest for both is the same.

Alternatively, if we consider individual particles of the disc instead of the disc as as whole, we will see that the particles of the fast spinning disc has more linear momentum than that of the slow spinning disc.

The rate of change of momentum is force.

This implies that the particles of the fast spinning disc will need more opposing force to come to rest than that of the slow spinning disc if the time interval to come to rest for both is the same.

Comment: Thank you soooo much!  This is perfect!

Comment: Thanks. I am glad that I have been able to help you.

Comment: small nitpick :rate of change of angular momentum is torque , but nevertheless given radius to be constant we need to apply more force so your explanation is valid

Answer (score 4):

**No, you don't.**

What you do need is to take away more energy from the faster spinning disk to make it stop as compared to the slower spinning disk.

So now, if you rephrase your question and add the condition - "stopping both these disks in the same time or within same angular displacement", then what you are saying makes sense. Because you can apply a tiny force (resulting in a torque that decelerates spinning) and the disk WILL STOP eventually.

Same happens for your car. A faster car with less braking force will also stop. It's just that it will take longer than the slower car.

Now that we have established that a faster disk or a faster car has more energy which it needs to get rid of, in order to stop, let's bring in the time component or a displacement (linear/angular) component.

We need to extract more energy in the same time duration or within same diplacement.

Lets look at it from a displacement angle first and take the example of the car for easy understanding:

Kinetic energy of the car = 0.5 x mass x speed x speed

You somehow need to apply an opposing force that does some work to take away the kinetic energy of the car. Faster car having more energy requires more work.

Work = force x distance

If you want the stopping distance to be the same, you need to increase the force.

Similar thing happens for your disk. Faster disk has more angular kinetic energy that you need to take away and hence you need to apply a higher torque. Assuming that you are applying the force at the same point in both cases (slower and faster disk), your force should be higher for the faster spinning disk.

Answer (score -1):

I second @WayneConrad's comment.  The car has linear momentum orders of magnitude greater than the angular momentum of the wheels (and the wheels themselves also have linear momentum in the direction of travel).

The force necessary for a particular rate of deceleration (i.e. stopping) depends mostly the *linear* force needed to decelerate the car, and that force comes from the contact patches of the tires.  The braking force required to make that patch break free will vary with condition and speed, and a more friction on the brake rotor or drum means more force.  That's dictated by friction characteristics and not angular momentum in the wheel, whose mass is relatively miniscule compared to the car.

Better to consider wheels spinning freely in space: bicycles upside down, Ferris wheel, table saw, etc.

Comment: In the context of this question, the linear momentum of the car is coupled into the angular momentum of the wheel by the rolling constraint, so that from the perspective of the brake the car is just a high-inertia wheel.

Comment: I was questioning the example, which brings in linear momentum unrelated to the spin (which disappears from the system as soon as the tire locks up), the behavior of tire contact patch at different speeds, which is a non-linear relationship. In other words, brake lock-up is not a good empirical model for decelerating a spinning wheel unless the car is resting on its roof